# Table Annotations Invalid object name

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have a ADMINCIDENTS class with, schema "ADM" and Table "Incidents":

```
[Table("ADM.INCIDENTS")]

public class ADMINCIDENTS
{
    [Key]
    public int INCNUM { get; set; }

}
```

When I query my database, the sql code generated is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [inc].[INCNUM]
FROM [ADM.INCIDENTS] AS [inc]
```

Sql says that [ADM.INCIDENTS] is an invalid object.
**How do I annotate my table so that the sql query generated adds the schema in the front in brackets with the table in brackets after, like this:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [inc].[INCNUM]
FROM [ADM].[INCIDENTS] AS [inc]
```

Comment: You are mixing up schema name with table name. The original `[ADM.INCIDENTS]` is a table name. `[ADM].[INCIDENTS]`, ADM is a schema name, INCIDENTS is a table name.

Comment: Oh, Okay,  will rewrite my question to ask about including schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[Table("INCIDENTS", Schema="ADM")]

public class ADMINCIDENTS
{
    [Key]
    public int INCNUM { get; set; }

}
```

Take a look at this: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/table-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx